# CLLocationManager callbacks (locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation and locationManager:didFailWithError:) never called

Tags: iphone, ios, location, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to get the current location and I'm running on this issue:

90% of times aprox. it just does it OK: it gets the location and calls `didUpdateToLocation:` or it fails and calls `didFailWithError:`. Everything as expected.

But sometimes (*always in the iOS 4.2 Simulator and sometimes on a real iPhone 4S device), it's not able to get a location at all and it does not call any of the callbacks (sometimes it calls didFailWithError but 2 or 3 minutes after starting updating location, sometimes it never does it), so I can't find a way to be aware of that.

By the way, it's the device/simulator who is not able to get the location because, when this occurs, the Maps application does **not** get the location either, showing the animated activity wheel indefinitely. The services are enabled and everything is well configured since it works most of the times.

So, the question: is there a way I can be aware of this circumstance and info the user?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to work around this issue is to set a timer and inform the user that a location fix could not be obtained if neither of the delegate methods gets called after a reasonable amount of time (say, 20 or 30 seconds). Then call `stopUpdatingLocation` and try again later.

I don't know if this behavior is documented but it seems that you are not guaranteed to get a response from the location manager as it may remain for a long time in a state where it can't yet get a location fix but does not observe an error, either.

Comment: That's exactly what I think and what I was thinking to do. Thank you for your response